# How to avoid the magnifying zoom my cropbox has in Cropper js?

Tags: javascript, html, django, cropperjs

Im using [Cropper JS](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) by fengyuanchen. When my cropper loads everything looks ok. But when I resize the window the cropbox zooms in the image.

This is how it loads:

[image]

And this is how it ends after the window resizing:

[image]

The is a zoom effect in the cropbox that I don't want. I'd like to be able to resize the window and avoid the zoom effect in the cropbox. Below are my cropper and container specifications:

Cropper:

```
croper() {
                const image = document.getElementById('image');
                const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                    responsive:false,
                    autoCropArea:1,
                    zoomable:false,
                    movable: false,
                    aspectRatio: NaN, viewMode: 2, crop(event) {
                        console.log("***********************************");
                        console.log(event.detail.x);
                        console.log(event.detail.y);
                        console.log(event.detail.width);
                        console.log(event.detail.height);
                        console.log(event.detail.rotate);
                        console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
                        console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
                        this.data = this.cropper.getData();
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this.data);
                        var contData = cropper.getContainerData(); //Get container data
                    },
                });
                cropper.setCropBoxData({ height: contData.height, width: contData.width  }) //set data
            }
```

Container:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card"  id="image_box" align="center">
            <div class="card text-center" style=" overflow: hidden; height: 100vh;">
                <!-- <div class="card-body"> -->
                <!-- <label id="file-drag"> -->
                <img id="image" style="max-width: 100%; display: block; " src="static/template/{{img}}.png" alt="Preview">
                <span id="preview">La vista previa de la imagen de la plantilla irá aquí</span>
                <!-- </label> -->
                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been encountering the same issue. I think there is a bug in the current version as the cropbox seems to want to infinitely scale to match what it thinks the image is doing. Setting the option `restore` to false seems to at least fix the infinite zoom, at the cost of the cropbox resetting to the default initial box when resizing the window.

```
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                    restore: false,
                });
```